# Como receptar señal que envia el hardware a mi aplicacion echa en c# con visual studio

Tags: c#, windows-forms, visual-studio-2017, hardware

La aplicacion que tengo recibe una señal de un dispositivo touch.
y cambia los valores que el texto muestra en Form.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el (calificador) de atencion al cliente como se nombra al proyecto recibe la senal del hardware y cambia los textos como se muestra en la imagen.

pero necesito saber que senal me llega del hardware que esta conectado por usb  al computador, para poder llevar esas calificaciones a una base de datos.

Comment: Recomiendo "HIDSharp", un proyecto que hace acceso a data USB mucho más fácil.  Con él, pude captuar (y ver) el data enviado por mi pedal USB.

Comment: Gracias por la recomendacion, pero podria ayudarme con un pequeno ejemplo de como utilizar la herramienta que me mencionas, para receptar estas senales. Dustom

Comment: Es en inglés, pero tengo un lugar en github.  https://github.com/n9ds/HID  No es un programa útil, pero arranca.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que ya no llegamos a tiempo pues leo ahora la pregunta que dejaste en mi blog.
Aún y así por si alguien mas lo necesita..

Entiendo que haces referencia a las "señales de hardware" asociadas a las entradas de control del puerto serie:

- Clear to send
- Data set ready

También tienes la posibilidad de detectar los eventos de Carrier detect, Break, o Llamada (ring) si tienes un modem conectado.

**IMPORTANTE**, Si estas utilizando un adaptador **USB/Serie**, no todos parsean todas las señales.

Tienes una respuesta sobre este tema en VB del 2011 :

https://blogs.msmvps.com/peplluis/2011/01/16/se-241-ales-de-control-del-puerto-serie-a-trav-233-s-del-pinchanged/

Te adjunto lo mismo para C# (no esta verificado, solo lo posteo a nivel de idea)

```
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SerialPort myPort = new SerialPort();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // las tramas finalizan con
            myPort.NewLine = "\r\n";
            // tiempo maximo de espera lectura trama completa
            myPort.ReadTimeout = 1000;
            // 
            myPort.DataReceived += MyPort_DataReceived;
            myPort.PinChanged   += MyPort_PinChanged;
        }

        void MyPort_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {                
                var bytesReceived = myPort.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                // throw timeout si no recibe una trama que finalize con (LF/CR) en un segundo;
            }
        }

        void MyPort_PinChanged(object sender, SerialPinChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (e.EventType)
            {
                case SerialPinChange.CtsChanged:
                    break;
                case SerialPinChange.DsrChanged:
                    break;
                case SerialPinChange.CDChanged:
                    break;
                case SerialPinChange.Break:
                    break;
                case SerialPinChange.Ring:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```